# How to customize text colors in the material ui in v 1.0.0

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello I try to customize the primary text-colors of the material ui,

I did this to customize the primary color:

```
const blue = {
  50: '#3ea5d7',
  100: '#3ea5d7',
  200: '#3ea5d7',
  300: '#3ea5d7',
  400: '#3ea5d7',
  500: '#3ea5d7',
  600: '#3ea5d7',
  700: '#3ea5d7',
  800: '#3ea5d7',
  900: '#3ea5d7',
  A100: '#3ea5d7',
  A200: '#3ea5d7',
  A400: '#3ea5d7',
  A700: '#3ea5d7',
  contrastDefaultColor: 'light',
};

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
  },
```

but I didnt get it how to customize the Text color. How to do this?

Comment: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

Comment: I mean the 1.0.0 Version of material ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out how it works:

To override classes you need to write exactly the override name of the component, for example button is MuiButton. The override works in the same order like the class names, f.e. if I have .MuiButton-label-1607 as class ther should be

```
overrides: {
  MuiButton: {
    label: {
      color: 'white', .....
```

to override the color of the label, so I have finally:

```
const blue = {
  50: '#3ea5d7',
  100: '#3ea5d7',
  200: '#3ea5d7',
  300: '#3ea5d7',
  400: '#3ea5d7',
  500: '#3ea5d7',
  600: '#3ea5d7',
  700: '#3ea5d7',
  800: '#3ea5d7',
  900: '#3ea5d7',
  A100: '#3ea5d7',
  A200: '#3ea5d7',
  A400: '#3ea5d7',
  A700: '#3ea5d7',
  contrastDefaultColor: 'light',
};

const yellow = {
  50: '#3ea5d7',
  100: '#3ea5d7',
  200: '#3ea5d7',
  300: '#3ea5d7',
  400: '#3ea5d7',
  500: '#3ea5d7',
  600: '#3ea5d7',
  700: '#3ea5d7',
  800: '#3ea5d7',
  900: '#3ea5d7',
  A100: '#3ea5d7',
  A200: '#3ea5d7',
  A400: '#3ea5d7',
  A700: '#3ea5d7',
  contrastDefaultColor: 'light',
};

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: createPalette({
    primary: blue,
    secondary: yellow,
    accent: yellow,
  }),
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      raisedPrimary: {
        color: 'white',
      },
      raisedAccent: {
        color: 'white',
      },
    },
    MuiCheckbox: {
      checked: {
        color: '#607d8b',
      },
    },
    MuiAppBar: {
      colorPrimary: {
        color: 'white',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The key is `overrides` not `override` (notice the pluralisation) in your first code chunk. [Documentation link](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type).

Comment: Rather than repeating the hex string over and over again, I recommend defining your palette once and then referencing it elsewhere.